# Which texts mention Saraswati as a mighty river and which texts say that it had dried up?

Tags: saraswati

Rig Veda talks about Saraswati as a mighty river (from Quora)

> 2.41.6 - Sarasvati is described as naditama, ambitama, devitama or the best river, best mother and best Goddess

> 6.52.6 - Sarasvati is made swollen by many rivers (pinvamana sindhubhiH)

> 7.95.2 - Sarasvati flows from mountains to the ocean (giribhyaH A samudrAt)

> 10.177 - Mandala 10 is the last portion of Rig Veda in terms of chronology. Even this book has hymns which pray to Sarasvati for continuation of sustenance and good fortune [9]

Which other texts talk about Saraswati as a major river and when does it start getting described as "dried up"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lord Balarama undertook a pilgrimage along the bank of Saraswati in Mahabharata. Many tirthas along the river are mentioned. It seems that a large fraction of Saraswati was still flowing at that time.

> Janamejaya said, 'Tell me, O foremost of men, the features, the
> origin, and the merit of the several tirthas of the Saraswati and the
> ordinances to be observed while sojourning there! ...'

**Mahabharata, Salya Parva, Chapter 35**

Mahabharata says that the river is lost at a place called Vinasana.

> Vaisampayana said, '... And since the Saraswati, in consequence of
> such contempt, is lost at that spot, the Rishis, for that reason, O
> chief of the Bharatas, always name the place as **Vinasana**...'

**Mahabharata Salya Parva, Chapter 37**